# How can I auto-resize a video in HTML?

Tags: html

I currently have this:

```
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media"><source src="...." type="video/mp4"></video>
```

It turns out, that half of the video is cut out of the screen, and I can't fix it.
Also, if you could help with this too, I'd like to know how to play the video in javascript.

Thanks!

Here is what I tried vs what I am expecting:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add attributes responsible for width and height.

As an example:

```
<video id="Test_Video" width="400" height="240" controls>
    <source src="gfg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

the size is in pixels. If you want you can also specify it in % f.ex `width="100%"`

Comment: This kind of worked, but now, the controls are down at the bottom and the video is in the middle of the page, I want it to be on the top center, and the controls on top of the video..

Comment: @Dany, position of the video depends on your div .css
Maybe you have some margin-top attribute there. Play with the values and attributes.

Comment: Notte: the `<center>` element has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) for at least 10 years.